# Golang and NSQ (bitly)

Tags: go, nsq

So kind of a noob here but I can't seem to find any examples or help anywhere. I have a working instance of NSQ, can register tasks, consumers, etc. Unfortunately I did not originally set the system up. What I am trying to do is figure out how to activate some of the built in command line tools that NSQ offers ( nsq_to_file, nsq_tail, etc. ). I found documentation on how to fire them but have no idea where to fire them from.

When I try `nsq_tail --channel=MyTestChannel --topic=test --lookupd-http-address=127.0.0.1:4161` i get nsq_tail command not found. The only other thing I know is that NSQ is managed by docker in our circumstance. Any help / a shove in the right direction would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did some digging and answered my own question. Hopefully this helps someone since the docs dont really exist:

1. Make sure NSQ is running by checking out the dashboard: localhost:4171
2. Install the NSQ library (different than nsq-go) `go get github.com/bitly/nsq`
3. Install godep, how bitly manages dependencies `go get github.com/tools/godep`
4. Go to bitly src directory `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/bitly`
5. Use docker to compile and test the nsq command line tools `sudo docker build nsq`

   - You should see about 5 or 6 steps run followed by a schlew of tests and a success message.
6. Run `nsq_tail` you should see something along the lines of `--topic is required`
7. Clap your hands, you just installed the command line tools for NSQ.

Might also need to install docker if you don't have it, not referenced above but FYI.